# JS Framework suggestion for Java based workflow web app

Tags: java, angular, workflow

I am building a workflow application with Java back-end.It's an application for a small engineering project that does a lot of workflow work. I'm working on design now and trying to choose JS Framework for front end. I am considering Angular 2, but it seems like there is a steep learning curve. I don't mind learning Angular, but wanted to ask others what alternatives are out there and if they would recommend Angular for a Java-based web app. UI could be SPA with multiple tabs or a hybrid SPA/MPA.
 Thanks!

Comment: This Question is off-topic here. Instead, try the sister site, [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I too suggest you consider [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/), [discussed several times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Asoftwarerecs.stackexchange.com+Vaadin&t=ffab&ia=web) on that sister site. See [the company’s YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/vaadinofficial) too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Vaadin? 
https://vaadin.com/

Basically it abstracts away the "client/server" architecture and you code your UI as if it were running locally as a Desktop application. The framework converts your Java code into runnable JavaScript *for* you. It's very neat. Drastically reduces the time it takes to build a full web app. Although I would say that if you need an extremely fast and responsive UI then there are faster frameworks out there.

"Build your web UIs in HTML or Java" - You can choose Java for your front end which may be a good choice as you already use Java for your back-end. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it as well. I just thought Angular or others may offer more when you need rich UI.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/). It has a learning curve but ain't as steep as Angular.